# Passing multiple refs from Child to Parent Component

Tags: reactjs, ref

I have a child and grandchild component and I want to access their refs in the Parent component for some DOM manipulation. 
There are multiple refs and two of the refs from the grandchild component needs to be a collection and one from the child component is a simple value

I have referred earlier questions on the ref and already tried the forwardRefs but I don't seem to be getting it right. Following is what I have tried

```
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    var renderChildren = this.props.data.nameValuePairs.map(function(
      item,
      index
    ) {
      return (
        <GrandChild
          title={item.title}
          description={item.description}
          index={index}
        />
      );
    });
    return <div ref={el => (this.childItem = el)}>{renderChildren}</div>;
  }
}

class GrandChild extends Component {
  render() {
    renderChild = (
      <div ref={el => (this.items[this.props.index] = el)}>
        <div ref={el => (this.items2[this.props.index] = el)}>
          <div>
            <h3>{this.props.headline}</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>{this.props.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    return renderChild;
  }
}

//need to access the refs here for DOM manipulation
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Child data={this.state.data} />;
  }
}
```